# Python: How can I get my code for opening a file to work on both Chrome and Firefox Webdrivers?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my following code I am managing to use Selenium Chromedriver to download a file from a website and check some of it's contents:

```
def FileCheck(self, filedirectory, fileextension, searchparameter):
total = 0
datetoday = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%I%M")
filename = "%s%s%s" % (filedirectory, datetoday, fileextension)
inputfile = open(filename)
for line in inputfile:
    if re.search(searchparameter, line):
        print('Search Match Found!')
        if line != 1 and line != 0:
            total += 1
print total
time.sleep(3)
```

I seem to be encountering issues with running this code on the Selenium driver for Mozilla Firefox. The web browser is reacting by displaying a Pop-up with different Open options that need to be clicked before the file is downloaded.

Does anyone know of a way to deal with this Firefox pop-up so that the above code will work on the Firefox web browser as it does on Chrome?

Comment: I don't see any mention about `Selenium` or `chromedriver` in your code. What is your issue about?  Show how do you handle file download prompt in `Chrome`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the Firefox pop-up upon download by importing FirefoxPreferences. I used the code below:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv/xls')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```